# Getting empty string when accessing server variable in client side

Tags: javascript, .net, session

Code:

I had set the `SessionData(EmployeeID) = "12345"` in server side and it first executes at `page_load`

Then, In client side

```
function getEmployeeId() {
        return "<%# SessionData("EmployeeID")%>";
    }
```

I am getting the empty string for the above code.

Also, I tried using `=` as  `"<%= SessionData("EmployeeID")%>";`
but I am getting the **error** as *"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
"*

Suggest me a solution.

Comment: write session data to a hiddenfield and then access it via `document.getElementByID`

Comment: @naveen, Thanks for your suggestion. I accompolished the goal by moving the script code from head tag to body tag. Also, I posted this as my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the issue by putting the `script` code inside the `Body` section. Previously, it was in the `Head` section.

I used the `"<%= SessionData("EmployeeID")%>";` code to access the server variable. It was working fine.